# Unexpected end of file ./bash_profile

Tags: bash, syntax

I'm completely new to bash syntax and completely unsure why I'm receiving an error in my shell saying:

> -bash: /Users/apple/.bash_profile: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file

My .bash_profile looks like so at the moment:

```
# include .bashrc if it exists
if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

I've noticed that commenting out the .bashrc portion removes the error.  Here is my simple .bashrc file for reference:

```
export PS1="\[\e[31m\]\u\[\e[m\]: \w "
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Any ideas as to what my issue could be?

Comment: No `fi` to close the if??

Comment: That would be the problem, thank you!  Leave an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: @Adi Bakija, `-bash: /Users/apple/.bash_profile: line 7` shows that you have an error on line 7 but you have posted only 3 lines, could you please check if you have posted all contents of bash_profile?

Comment: You could also switch to the same format as the `rvm` include: `[[ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]] && source "$HOME/.bashrc"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` should have a closing statement which is `fi`.